# ScrollView don't scroll all the way down - React Native

Tags: react-native

I've had a problem with my ScrollView for a few days, it doesn't want to scroll all the way down. However when I remove the View above the ScrollView, there is no more problem, but that is not what I am trying to do. Using a paddingBottom in the contentContainerStyle doesn't seem like the best solution in my opinion. Do you know how to fix this? And also, the flex: 1 bottom everything disappears.

This is a base on my component

Demo: https://gyazo.com/9e1425b3ebf582112813b02b02750192

```
<View style={{}}>
    <View style={{
        paddingBottom: 23,
        backgroundColor: '#b61414',
    }}>
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20 }}>
                <View>
                    <View style={{ marginRight: 15 }}></View>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text maxFontSizeMultiplier={1} style={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: 18 }}>{this.props.loggedIn.pseudonyme}</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ paddingBottom: 10, marginTop: 12 }} onPress={() => this._actionProfile()}>
                        <Icon maxFontSizeMultiplier={1} color="#fff" type="ionicon" name="ios-more" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
    <ScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Thank !

Comment: share a working expo snack where i can chek and revert what was the problem

Comment: Here : https://snack.expo.io/rJqvarJW8

Comment: whats the issue? you can use padding or margin bottom

Comment: Do we have to go through that so that the scroll goes all the way down? Isn't there a cleaner solution?